How to reduce CPU impact of sp_cdc_scan procedure in SQL Server when CDC is enabled on multiple databases?
I have enabled CDC on a few databases in my SQL Server instance. I noticed that enabling CDC on a database creates the sp_cdc_scan request, which runs continuously and consumes CPU time. This has resulted in a noticeable performance impact on other queries running on the server, causing everything to become slower.
When I disabled CDC, the queries ran faster. However, I'm unsure how to trace and benchmark the performance effectively to identify what specifically causes that performance issue.
What factors affect this? DB Transaction Log size?
From my understanding, the sp_cdc_scan procedure needs to run continuously because it checks the transaction log for changes every 5 seconds. If there are no changes, it waits until the next interval. I also understand that it doesn't scan the whole log every time; instead, it starts from where it left off last. So, even if the log size increases significantly, this shouldn't affect performance, as the changes within a 5-second interval are typically minimal.
How can I mitigate the CPU impact of sp_cdc_scan when CDC is enabled on multiple databases? Are there any best practices or configurations that can help manage or reduce the performance overhead?
Would using Change Tracking instead of CDC result in similar CPU usage issues? How does Change Tracking compare to CDC in terms of performance impact on the server?

To help answer that, it would be good to know the approximate size of these databases, how much data change happens, and the size of the machines running them.  It would also be nice to know what you would use the tracked information for.

Do you have some sql agent job that runs this cdc stuff? Perhaps you can just make it run a bit less often. You can look how disk is affected perhaps, in performance monitor?

Might be worth fiddling with the job settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-add-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
